# What can cause ajax calls to take much longer in IE than Chrome?

Tags: ajax, performance, google-chrome, internet-explorer, liferay-6

I am working on a Liferay-based portal which contains a number of dynamic portlets.

The load-time on Chrome is roughly half that of IE. There may be a number of factors but it appears to me that the AJAX calls take much longer in IE than in Chrome. The timings below show the (XHR filtered) results of identical requests. The same user is logged in and the page is refreshed.

What might be causing this difference?

Timing in Chrome 54:
[image: Timing in Chrome]

Timing in IE11:
[image: Timing in IE11]

**UPDATE**
Just found this question which is similar: [Can a XmlHttpRequest take more time in IE than in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718063/can-a-xmlhttprequest-take-more-time-in-ie-than-in-chrome?rq=1). The one answer suggests a link to Windows Authentication. However, all the requests are GETs and I see no indication of Authentication Challenges - simply a request and a -late- reply.

Comment: Chrome is much faster than most versions of IE.  I think its really that simple.  The newest version of Microsoft's browser for Window's 10 is much faster than other versions of IE.

Comment: What is happening with those requests? What is being returned?

Comment: @epascarello The requests are the same, the results are the same. The pages look identical. I haven't looked at each response but just at the timing.

Comment: https://blog.chromium.org/2009/12/technically-speaking-what-makes-google.html

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Might be related to this, but still no solution :(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292570/why-does-ie-wait-till-the-call-stack-is-empty-to-send-post-ajax-requests